# Is this code in C or Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, opengl-es

I am an iOS developer (very little experience) that develops in Swift. My next project is to make a two player tic tac toe game using Open Gl ES. Swift is not the best language choice for OpenGl ES development so I am starting to learn Objective C. I am following a book that expalins Open GL ES for iOS specifically, in Objective C. While reading the book they have the following data strucuture that stores vertices and they say it is an array. Here is the code...

```
static const SceneVertex vertices[] = {{{-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0}},{{ 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0}},{{-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0}}};
```

This does not look like an array in Objective-C. Is this in C? Also why are the initialization of the array is a little weird. Why are their curly braces instead of square brackets to initialize the array?

Comment: Objective C is a superset of C. Valid C code is valid Objective C code.

Comment: Correct, this is a plain C array, *not* an Objective-C NS{Mutable}Array, hence the curly braces.

Comment: Ok Thank you. One other question then. If I can implement C code in Objective C, then I can learn how to use Open GL ES in C and then implement it in an iOS app written in Objective-C? So draw the tic tac toe board in C and then have all the views, labels, buttons etc in Objective C?

Comment: This question should really contain the definition of `SceneVertex`, so that the initialization can be fully explained. And yes, you can write the GL code in C and implement the UI in Objective-C.

Comment: Sorry about that. Thank you, will do that then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format for initializing an array in C is to encase the values used to initialize the array in `{}`

[Initializing Arrays](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm)

```
double balance[] = {1000.0, 2.0, 3.4, 7.0, 50.0};
```